# При авторизации не вижу все базы данных в mysql

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql, база-данных, mysql

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
При входе в mysql через phpmyadmin я вижу все базы данных отлично, а если пытаюсь авторизироваться каким-либо другим способом (например через heidiSQL) то вижу в списке только БД Information_Schema. Даже если авторизироваться под root, других БД я почему-то не вижу.
Что может блокировать к ним доступ?
Заранее благодарен за ответ

Comment: единственный нормальный способ авторизрваться в mysql и диагностировать ошибки - mysql-client (commandline) да  и вообще это самый удобный способ управлять базой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас в настройках явно указана та база, которую нужно отображать. Выберите нужные базы или оставьте это поле пустым.

[image]

Comment: База там не была указана, поле пустое. Попробовал вручную прописать нужную мне базу, но после подключения при клике на базу мне выдало сообщение Unknown database

Comment: Ну ок. Тогда дела в другом - не вдаваясь в подробности: "через phpmyadmin" вы логинитесь "локально" с хоста базы, а с heidiSQL - со своего локального компа. Стало быть, надо смотреть права пользователей - скорее всего, у вас "с любого IP" разрешен доступ только на таблицу Information_Schema.
Откройте Tools->User Manager - там все будет показано: кто имеет какие привилегии.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с этим http://hashcode.ru/questions/306158#306169

Comment: Все, разобрался. Спасибо)